# DVD drive not mounted when DVD inserted in 16.04 - unless I use the "eject -t" command

Tags: 16.04, mount, dvd, eject

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 Server Edition, and I've discovered that the DVD drive does not mount when I insert a DVD and close the tray manually, but the drive is mounted if I issue `eject -t` to close the tray instead. I've tested multiple DVDs (all of them movies except one - a Windows installation DVD), and they all behave the same.

All of the DVDs I've tested mount automatically on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation, so I copied the libblkid.so.1 file from 14.04 onto this computer, as described in the workaround of this bug report: [Bug #1577768](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1577768) (Post #7).

Also, I tested the only CD I could find (an HP printer drivers CD), and it mounted without using `eject -t`.

Is there any reason why `eject -t` would cause different behaviour than closing the tray manually?